# why it is stated there the setup is incompatible?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

how to fix it and why is it stated that setup incompatible? The project was made in visual studio 2017 and now the project has to run in the updated version which is visual studio 2022.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WxWN.png)

im expecting a tutorial on how to fix this